# R- Turn dataframe into two pivot list

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 800K row and looks like something like this;

```
    v2 | v1 |  probs     | v1_name       | v2_name
--------------------------------------------------------
1 | 1  | 0  | 0.04417671 | type_id       | subtype_id
2 | 2  | 0  | 0.05752212 | risk_level_id | subtype_id
3 | 3  | 0  | 0.04411765 | type_id       | gender
4 | 4  | 0  | 0.02510460 | legual_size   | risk_level_id
5 | 5  | 0  | 0.07296137 | type_id       | sector_id
6 | 6  | 0  | 0.04743083 | risk_level_id | type_id
```

Both v1_name and v2_name has unique 18 values. My intention is forming two list. One stores the relationship and the other stores the weights. I have tried dplyr groupby, summarize etc but got lost.

```
graph <- list(type_id_0 = c("subtype_id_1", "gender_3","sector_id_5"),
              risk_level_id_0 = c("subtype_id_2", "type_id_6"),
              legual_size_0 = c("risk_level_id_4"))


weights <- list(type_id_0 = c(0.04417671, 0.04411765,0.07296137),
                risk_level_id_0 = c(0.05752212,0.04743083),
                legual_size_0 = c(0.02510460))
```

I'm using R version 3.3.3 and I am stucked on this version, because the project requires it.

Any idea and helps would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create vector by pasting v1_names and v1 and use this vector to filter the data frame. Then create a loop for each combination of v1_names and v1.

```
cmb <- with(df, paste(v1_name, v1, sep = "_"))

ls1 <- list()
for (i in unique(with(df, paste(v1_name, v1, sep = "_")))) {
  ls1[[i]] <- with(df[cmb == i,], paste(v2_name, v2, sep = "_"))
}
     
ls2 <- list()
for (i in unique(with(df, paste(v1_name, v1, sep = "_")))) {
  ls2[[i]] <- df[cmb == i, ]$probs
}
```

List 1:

```
ls1
$type_id_0
[1] "subtype_id_1" "gender_3"     "sector_id_5" 

$risk_level_id_0
[1] "subtype_id_2" "type_id_6"   

$legual_size_0
[1] "risk_level_id_4"
```

List 2:

```
ls2
$type_id_0
[1] 0.04417671 0.04411765 0.07296137

$risk_level_id_0
[1] 0.05752212 0.04743083

$legual_size_0
[1] 0.0251046
```